# Difference between (localdb)\v11.0 and .\sqlexpress in connection string

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

What the difference between **(localdb)\v11.0** and **.\sqlexpress**  in connection string?

I am using master database file **.mdf** local database using SQL Server 2012

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;
```

**and**

```
Data Source=.\sqlexpress;
```

What's the best or favored to use in connection string?

I try both of them in my connection string but I found or I think the **v11.0**  it's best than **.\sqlserver** is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Express is a service-based version of SQL Server i.e. it runs as a service all the time, independently of other applications. When you say `.\SQLEXPRESS` you are looking for a named instance of SQL Server called `SQLEXPRESS` that is on your local machine and connected to via a shared memory interface (that's what the dot is).

Local DB is a deployment option for SQL Server Express that runs as an attached process to another application, instead of as a service. It can also be started and stopped by the local db utility. Mostly it's used attached to applications like Visual Studio that just need to use a SQL Server for a while during development, but don't need it running all the time. When you connect to `(localdb)\v11.0` you are connecting to one of these attached instances, and in this case using version 11 (you can have multiple versions of localdb on the same machine).

Comment: Either would work OK. If you want a service running all the time (e.g. many apps talking to it), then use a SQLEXPRESS instance. If you just want to use it for development in VS, then just use localdb.